# van't hoff factor

Tags: physical-chemistry

Basically I was doing a freezing point depression question where enough information was given to calculate the van't Hoff factor(i) which was 1.86. Anyways the question was asking to calculate the percent dissociation based on the above value. Note: the equation given was AB3 -> A + 3B so assuming no dissociation i would have equaled 4. Everyone I asked is conflicted whether the answer is 45.5 or 28 percent. Which one is correct?